Canvas not scaling UI elements
I just found out about the "scale with screen size" feature and now wanted to use it. Because I am working on a 2560x1440 display, that is what I used, but if I switch my view to 1920x1080, the UI does not scale and move to where it should be. Any ideas?
(In the pictures, my UI is the two bars)

try setting Screen Match Mode in Canvas Scaler to 1 or 0. usualy works more reliably

Check the anchors for your UI elements, press on one of them or both and at the top of the inspector, inside rect transform there should be a small square like on this:

Press it and set the anchors to what you want (top left). It should work after that.
